# can't launch spark job on aws using spark 1.4 and hadoop 2.4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I have an existing Spark job that runs successfully on an AWS EC2 on-demand cluster created using spark-ec2.  It runs against Spark 1.0.1 and Hadoop 1.  I decided it was time to upgrade, so I built a new Amazon Machine Image (AMI) using Spark 1.4 pre-built for Hadoop 2.4.  The cluster starts fine, but submitting jobs is no love.  I get an endless stream of executor running, loading, exiting.  What do I need to do in Spark 1.4 or Hadoop 2 to get my jobs running again?

```
    15/06/24 18:20:20 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.4.0
    15/06/24 18:20:21 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    15/06/24 18:20:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
    15/06/24 18:20:22 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
    15/06/24 18:20:22 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
    15/06/24 18:20:23 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
    15/06/24 18:20:23 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
    15/06/24 18:20:24 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@172.31.22.209:53881]
    15/06/24 18:20:24 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 53881.
    15/06/24 18:20:24 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
    15/06/24 18:20:24 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
    15/06/24 18:20:24 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /mnt/spark/spark-aad8e94f-2abd-4755-bd78-7813ed60ca1e/blockmgr-c744ec31-c0af-4d53-8580-6af3422f296a
    15/06/24 18:20:24 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 267.3 MB
    15/06/24 18:20:24 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /mnt/spark/spark-aad8e94f-2abd-4755-bd78-7813ed60ca1e/httpd-3cfae729-b20d-40bf-afb0-7d4c916bc5bb
    15/06/24 18:20:24 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
    15/06/24 18:20:24 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 34749.
    15/06/24 18:20:24 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
    15/06/24 18:20:25 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
    15/06/24 18:20:25 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://ec2-52-27-77-155.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4040
    15/06/24 18:20:26 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/WidgetLogProcessor-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar at http://172.31.22.209:34749/jars/WidgetLogProcessor-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with timestamp 1435170026446
    15/06/24 18:20:26 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ec2-52-27-77-155.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7077/user/Master...
    15/06/24 18:20:27 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20150624182027-0000
    15/06/24 18:20:28 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/0 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:28 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/0 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:28 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/0 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:28 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/0 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:28 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 54542.
    15/06/24 18:20:28 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 54542
    15/06/24 18:20:28 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
    15/06/24 18:20:28 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 172.31.22.209:54542 with 267.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 172.31.22.209, 54542)
    15/06/24 18:20:28 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
    15/06/24 18:20:28 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
    15/06/24 18:20:29 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(145808) called with curMem=0, maxMem=280248975
    15/06/24 18:20:29 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 142.4 KB, free 267.1 MB)
    15/06/24 18:20:30 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(13239) called with curMem=145808, maxMem=280248975
    15/06/24 18:20:30 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 12.9 KB, free 267.1 MB)
    15/06/24 18:20:30 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 172.31.22.209:54542 (size: 12.9 KB, free: 267.3 MB)
    15/06/24 18:20:30 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at WidgetLogProcessor.scala:32
    15/06/24 18:20:30 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/0 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:30 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/0 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:30 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 0
    15/06/24 18:20:30 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/1 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:30 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/1 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:30 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/1 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:30 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/1 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:32 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/1 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:32 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/1 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:32 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 1
    15/06/24 18:20:32 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/2 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:32 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/2 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:32 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/2 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:32 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/2 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:34 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/2 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:34 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/2 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:34 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 2
    15/06/24 18:20:34 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/3 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:34 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/3 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:34 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/3 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:34 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/3 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at RDDUserSegmentMapper.scala:12
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at RDDUserSegmentMapper.scala:12) with 2 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0(collect at RDDUserSegmentMapper.scala:12)
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at WidgetLogProcessor.scala:32), which has no missing parents
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(3184) called with curMem=159047, maxMem=280248975
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.1 KB, free 267.1 MB)
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1854) called with curMem=162231, maxMem=280248975
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1854.0 B, free 267.1 MB)
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 172.31.22.209:54542 (size: 1854.0 B, free: 267.3 MB)
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:874
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at WidgetLogProcessor.scala:32)
    15/06/24 18:20:35 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
    15/06/24 18:20:36 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/3 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:36 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/3 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:36 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 3
    15/06/24 18:20:36 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/4 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:36 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/4 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:36 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/4 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:36 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/4 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:38 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/4 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:38 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/4 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:38 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 4
    15/06/24 18:20:38 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/5 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:38 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/5 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:38 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/5 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:38 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/5 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:40 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/5 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:40 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/5 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:40 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 5
    15/06/24 18:20:40 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/6 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:40 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/6 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:40 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/6 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:41 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/6 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:43 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/6 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:43 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/6 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:43 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 6
    15/06/24 18:20:43 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/7 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:43 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/7 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:43 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/7 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:43 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/7 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:45 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/7 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:45 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/7 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:45 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 7
    15/06/24 18:20:45 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/8 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:45 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/8 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:45 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/8 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:45 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/8 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:47 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/8 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:47 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/8 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:47 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 8
    15/06/24 18:20:47 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/9 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:47 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/9 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:47 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/9 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:47 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/9 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:49 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/9 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:49 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/9 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:49 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 9
    15/06/24 18:20:49 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/10 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:49 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/10 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:49 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/10 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:49 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/10 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:50 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
    15/06/24 18:20:51 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/10 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:51 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/10 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:51 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 10
    15/06/24 18:20:51 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/11 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:51 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/11 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:51 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/11 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:51 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/11 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:53 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/11 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:53 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/11 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:53 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 11
    15/06/24 18:20:53 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/12 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:53 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/12 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:53 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/12 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:53 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/12 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:55 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/12 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:55 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/12 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:55 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 12
    15/06/24 18:20:55 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/13 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:55 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/13 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:55 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/13 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:55 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/13 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:57 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/13 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:57 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/13 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:57 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 13
    15/06/24 18:20:57 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/14 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:57 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/14 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:57 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/14 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:57 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/14 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:20:59 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/14 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:20:59 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/14 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:20:59 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 14
    15/06/24 18:20:59 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/15 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:20:59 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/15 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:20:59 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/15 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:20:59 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/15 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:21:01 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/15 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:21:01 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/15 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:21:01 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 15
    15/06/24 18:21:01 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/16 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:21:01 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/16 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:21:01 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/16 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:21:01 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/16 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:21:03 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/16 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:21:03 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/16 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:21:03 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 16
    15/06/24 18:21:03 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/17 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:21:03 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/17 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:21:03 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/17 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:21:03 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/17 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:21:05 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
    15/06/24 18:21:05 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/17 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:21:05 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/17 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:21:05 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 17
    15/06/24 18:21:05 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/18 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:21:06 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/18 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:21:06 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/18 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:21:06 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/18 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:21:08 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/18 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:21:08 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/18 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:21:08 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 18
    15/06/24 18:21:08 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/19 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:21:08 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/19 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:21:08 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/19 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:21:08 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/19 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:21:10 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/19 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:21:10 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/19 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:21:10 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 19
    15/06/24 18:21:10 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/20 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:21:10 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/20 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:21:10 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/20 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:21:10 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/20 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:21:12 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/20 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:21:12 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/20 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:21:12 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 20
    15/06/24 18:21:12 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/21 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:21:12 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/21 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:21:12 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/21 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:21:12 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/21 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:21:14 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/21 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:21:14 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/21 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:21:14 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 21
    15/06/24 18:21:14 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/22 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:21:14 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/22 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:21:14 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/22 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:21:14 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/22 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:21:16 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/22 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:21:16 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/22 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:21:16 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 22
    15/06/24 18:21:16 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/23 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:21:16 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/23 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:21:16 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/23 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:21:16 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/23 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:21:18 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/23 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
    15/06/24 18:21:18 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20150624182027-0000/23 removed: Command exited with code 1
    15/06/24 18:21:18 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 23
    15/06/24 18:21:18 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20150624182027-0000/24 on worker-20150624181352-172.31.31.193-56683 (172.31.31.193:56683) with 1 cores
    15/06/24 18:21:18 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20150624182027-0000/24 on hostPort 172.31.31.193:56683 with 1 cores, 2.4 GB RAM
    15/06/24 18:21:18 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/24 is now LOADING
    15/06/24 18:21:18 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/24 is now RUNNING
    15/06/24 18:21:20 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20150624182027-0000/24 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
```

Comment: Does starting the spark shell on the cluster work? How are you submitting your jobs? Does your assembly jar (if applicable) mark spark-core as provided? Can you post the logs from one of the workers?

Comment: I think my upgrade process is at fault.  To get to my current AMI, I ran spark-ec2 and let it install everything and then saved that image.  To upgrade, I thought I could just install spark-1.4 on existing AMI but I'm thinking there are lots of other components that need to be upgraded as well.  So I'm going back to the start and letting spark-ec2 run and install everything.  I'll update the question when that is complete.

Comment: Operator error in Spark land.  I let spark-ec2 deploy from its AMI and all is well.